# Angular 4 - apply filter on button click

Tags: angular, observable

I'm having trouble with applying filter on mat-table on button click event.

**button in component.html**:

```
<button #button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilter();" value="2017-01">January</button>
```

**component.ts applyFilter method call:**

```
 @ViewChild('button') button: ElementRef;

applyFilter(){
Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(() => {
    if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
    this.dataSource.filter = this.button.nativeElement.value;
  })};
```

Filter on input field works great but when I'm trying to add `@ViewChild` on button, I'm getting error in console output like:

> ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target

I could not find any documentation about .fromEvent rxjs so any help would be great. Thanks

**EDIT**:

This part of code works fine:

```
    <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
  <input matInput #filter placeholder="Search">
</mat-form-field>

      Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(() => {
      if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
      this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
    });
```

I want to hide/replace input field with 12 buttons (months) that will every each of them apply specific filter on mat-table

Comment: you want to change the button value based on certain events is that so ?

Comment: i want to apply filter on mat table when you make event click on that button

Comment: so click is a function you can directly use that function why going for observables have a `applyFilter()` function in component

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but i don't know how to apply it in context of mat-table filter. I've tried with static binding and it didn't work

Comment: filter that table array in that function and your table will be filtered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:
HTML:

```
<button #button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="this.customFilter = getMonth('01'); changeFilter($event)">January</button>

<input [(ngModel)]="this.customFilter"  #filter matInput placeholder="Search">
```

Component.ts:

```
changeFilter(event){
  this.dataSource.filter = this.customFilter;
};
getMonth(val){
  let date: any = new Date();
  let yyyy = date.getUTCFullYear();
  return yyyy+'-'+val;
}
Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(() => {
    if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
    this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static value for your button "2017-01", so you can try this:

```
applyFilter(){
    if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
    this.dataSource.filter = "2017-01";
}
```

Or the button value can change, so try:

```
<button #button mat-raised-button color="primary" #mybutton (click)="applyFilter(mybutton.value);" value="2017-01">January</button>

applyFilter(value:any){
    if (!this.dataSource) { return; }
    this.dataSource.filter = value:any;
}
```